# How to load audio file into AudioContext like stream?

Tags: javascript, audio, xmlhttprequest, fetch, audiocontext

For example i want to load 100MB mp3 file into AudioContext, and i can do that with using XMLHttpRequest.

But with this solution i need to load all file and only then i can play it, because `onprogress` method don't return data.

```
xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
   console.log(this.response); //return null 
};
```

Also i tried to do that with `fetch` method, but this way have same problem.

```
fetch(url).then((data) => {
   console.log(data); //return some ReadableStream in body, 
                      //but i can't find way to use that
});
```

There is any way to load audio file like stream in client JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to handle the ajax response in a streaming way.
there is no standard way to do this until fetch & ReadableStream have properly been implemented across all the browsers

I'll show you the most correct way according to the new standard how you should deal with streaming a ajax response

```
// only works in Blink right now
fetch(url).then(res => {
     let reader = res.body.getReader()
     let pump = () => {
         reader.read().then(({value, done}) => {
             value // chunk of data (push chunk to audio context)
             if(!done) pump()
         })
     }
     pump()
})
```

Firefox is working on implementing streams but until then you need to use xhr and `moz-chunked-arraybuffer`
IE/edge has `ms-stream` that you can use but it's more complicated

Comment: Thanks, it's looks fine. But last problem is value it's not a ArrayBuffer, and i can't put it in audio context.

Comment: `value.buffer` is a ArrayBuffer (like with any other typed array `new Uint32Array().buffer`)

Comment: Really, Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

How can I send `value.buffer` to `AudioContext`?

This only plays the first chunk and it doesn't work correctly.

```js
const context = new AudioContext()
const source = context.createBufferSource()
source.connect(context.destination)
        
const reader = response.body.getReader()
        
while (true) {
    await reader.read()
    const { done, value } = await reader.read()

    if (done) {
        break
    }

    const buffer = await context.decodeAudioData(value.buffer)
    source.buffer = buffer
    source.start(startTime)
}
```